# How can the application user save data to one of his own cloud storage?

Tags: file-upload, cloud, storage, codenameone

In my cn1 application, I want to make it possible for the user to back up their own cloud storage. For example, your own Dropbox account.

I was looking for a solution on the WEB. I think what I found (dropbox-codenameone-sdk) I can only manage a known account because I need to know consumerSecret and consumerKey. When I write the code, I don't know the actual user account information.
Based on the operation of other applications, I assume I have to log in to the actual user his account (eg Dropbox).

Please help what API calls can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Share API in Display. You can zip the data using the zip cn1lib and save it in a file within the file system then use the share API to let the user pick a native app to share it with. On the simulator it will have options such as email/facebook but on the device you should have more options.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your advice. This opportunity avoided my attention. It's evident now.

Comment: Hi,
How do I share a different type of file than image? Whatever mime type I set, the simulator treats it as an image. On Android phones, the filename is prefixed (IMG_...) to attac to a mail or send to DropBox. Therefore, the file cannot be found. 
Please help.

Comment: The native device acts very differently from the simulator. You need to use the API there.

Comment: Hi,  I can't attach image and snippet as comment.  Please read my answer below.

Comment: The simulator assumes proper images which fails there but since it works on the devices I don't see the problem?
FYI you need to edit the question not add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm using the API properly. Although I did not set correctly the file access on my phone.

However, the error occured in the simulator.

The mail and DropBox sharing  on my android phone is successful.
I don't like the file getting a prefix (IMG_20200112_204126_). Can I change this?

I include screenshots and a code snippet.

Best regards, Péter

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]
[image: image4]
[image: image5]

```
public ShareForm(Resources resourceObjectInstance, Form parentForm) {
this.parentForm = parentForm; 
this.theme = resourceObjectInstance;

Layout layout = new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
setLayout(layout);

getToolbar().setBackCommand("", e -> {
    this.parentForm.showBack();
});

/* file exist on simulator */
/*        String filePath = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + "temp/vendeg_201807011754.json"; */
/* file exist on phone */
String filePath = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/stratos.pdf";

String mimeType = "application/octet-stream";

boolean exist = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists(filePath);
long size = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getLength(filePath);

SpanLabel spanLabel0 = new SpanLabel("File path: " + filePath);
SpanLabel spanLabel1 = new SpanLabel("File exist: " + exist);
SpanLabel spanLabel2 = new SpanLabel("File size: " + size);

ShareButton shareButton = new ShareButton();
shareButton.setText("Share data (ShareButton)");
shareButton.addActionListener(e-> {
    shareButton.setImageToShare(filePath, mimeType);
    shareButton.actionPerformed(e);
});


Button shareButton1 = new Button("Share data (Share API in Display)");
FontImage.setMaterialIcon(shareButton1, FontImage.MATERIAL_SHARE);
shareButton1.addActionListener(e -> {
    Display.getInstance().share(null, filePath, mimeType, shareButton1.getBounds(new Rectangle()));
});

addComponent(spanLabel0);
addComponent(spanLabel1);
addComponent(spanLabel2);
addComponent(shareButton);
addComponent(shareButton1);
```

}